# Having problems accessing a property throughout multiple classes

Tags: ios, objective-c

Ok. I am assuming my misunderstanding of ARC is why I am posting this, but here it goes. So I have a class, lets' call it class **A**, that I call and reference and works beautifully how I want it to in class **B**. Now, when I access class **A** inside of class **C**, a property I need returns a null value. Note: Because of the way my method is structured, I need to only access the property each call, not call the method because the method returns a different result each time I call it. What am I doing wrong? Here's how I declare the property in my header file in class **A**:

.h

```
@property (retain) NSString * userKey;
```

Here's the method where I set it:

```
-(NSString *)grabUserKey{
    //Grabs a string from a web service each time it is called
    NSString *getUserKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/webservices/***/mobile_services_ios7.cfc?method=create_account&client_key=%@", [self grabHomeURl],CLIENT_KEY];

    NSLog(@"%@", getUserKey);
    NSString * user_key = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:getUserKey] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    //I only need this property once and only once. However, this property is null the second time I call it
    self.userKey = user_key;
    return user_key;
}
```

Now, when I try to use this property in another method, inside of the same class (emphasis.) I get a null result the second time I reference it:

```
-(NSString *) returnFilePath{
    NSString *userDBPath  = [PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:CLIENT_KEY];
    //self.userKey returns null when called in class C, but not in class A
    NSString * userFilePath = [userDBPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.userKey];

    return userFilePath;
}
```

Here's how I initialize class **A** of class **C:**

.h

```
@property (retain) RetriveFilePath * filePath;
```

.m

```
 _filePath = [[RetriveFilePath alloc]init];
  NSString * localShow = [_filePath returnFilePath];
```

So why is it that when I access class A in class B (The first time class A is accessed during compile time), works. But When I access class A in class C, I get null userKey? Hopefully I explained clearly for everyone.

Comment: Are you sure you requested your userKey from class C to class A after the API call finished? Moreover, why are you using `retain` instead of `strong`?

Comment: Did you invoke `grabUserKey` in class C before you call `returnFilePath`?

Comment: @trick14 good second point. just switched it over to strong, still the same null result inside of class c. Not really understanding your first point. Do you mean something like: [_filepath userkey]? Your second comment is where my situation get's tricky. I can only call the grabUserKey method once and only once. Each time I call the grabUserKey, I get a different result which is something I can't have. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @trick14 I realize that might be confusing because my instance method "grabUserKey"returns a string. It technically should be just a void method that sets the property "self.userKey" if that makes sense.

Comment: Class A is the `RetriveFilePath`. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set a user key at class A's property `NSString *userKey`. It's not a persistent data. You have to save the data somewhere else like `NSUserDefault`.

According to the code you appended,

```
_filePath = [[RetriveFilePath alloc]init];
NSString * localShow = [_filePath returnFilePath];
```

You instantiated `RetriveFilePath` and tried to get userKey; However there's no userKey in RetriveFilePath coz you haven't get the data yet.

Wherever you invoke the `[_filePath grabUserKey]`, it's not the same instance with the _filePath.

Use NSUserDefault or make the class singleton.